# Is Regexp.last_match thread safe?

Tags: ruby

This is the code that I'm looking at:

```
def method_missing(id, *args)
    return self.find(Regexp.last_match(1),  args[0]) if id.id2name =~ /find_by_(.+)/
    raise NoMethodError
end
```

What happens if I have multiple threads calling `Regexp.last_match`?

What happens if I have multiple threads calling the object with the `method_missing` method?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be thread safe? Are you getting wrong values?

Comment: No, but since it is calling an class method, Im thinking it is accessing a class variable. I think it has to be thread safe, but just to make sure.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Ruby 1.9.2 platform docs state that calling `Regexp.last_match` is equivalent to reading the special `$~` global variable.

From "The Ruby Programming Language", pg 318: "it is important to remember that $~ and the variables derived from it are all thread-local and method-local."

So `Regexp.last_match` *is* thread-safe. As for the other methods you are using in `method_missing`, I believe they are thread-safe as well. (If anybody knows differently, please edit this post.)

Answer (score 12):

### TL;DR

Yes, [Regexp special global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) are thread-safe because they aren't truly globals. Despite the fact that the variables have the word "global" in the name, the documentation says:

> These global variables are thread-local and method-local variables.

### Threads

You can prove this to yourself in the irb or pry REPL. For example, to test the variables' scope inside threads:

```
# Ensure $~ and friends are nil in case this isn't a fresh REPL.
''.match /foo/

# Make this variable available inside the thread block.
thread_match = nil

Thread.new do
  'foo'.match /(foo)/
  thread_match = "In thread: #{$1.inspect}"
end

[thread_match, "Global value: #{$1.inspect}"]
#=> ["In thread: \"foo\"", "Global value: nil"]
```

### Methods

These special variables aren't even truly global when used within a method. Consider the following:

```
def foo
  'foo'.match /(foo)/
  p $1
end 

[foo, $1]
#=> ["foo", nil]
```

### Conclusion

In other words, the Regexp special variables *look* like true globals because of the `$` prefix, but do not persist outside the enclosing thread or method. To what extent that justifies calling them "globals" at all is something you'd have to take up with the language designers, or file a bug about if you feel strongly that it's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to suggest it isn't thread safe using the method in @Todd A. Jacobs' answer.

```
➜  ~ irb
irb(main):001:0> thread_match = nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> Thread.new do
irb(main):003:1* /([[:alpha:]])*/.match('BF92')
irb(main):004:1> thread_match = "In thread: #{$1.inspect}"
irb(main):005:1> end
=> #<Thread:0x00007f8cfc971090@(irb):2 run>
irb(main):006:0> thread_match
=> "In thread: \"F\""
irb(main):007:0>
```

Comment: This is showing that the variable `thread_match` is not thread-local, but it does nothing to disprove that `$1` is thread-local: it is only accessed in the same thread as the regex is run