# Rails 3 - Check if string/text includes a certain word/character via regex in controller

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I am working on a quoting mechanism in my app, where it should be possible to simply type #26, for example, in the comment form in order to quote comment 26 of that topic.
To check if a user wants to quote one or more comments in the first place, I put an if condition after my current_user.comments.build and before @comment.save.
But, just to make my question a bit more general and easier to adapt:

```
if @comment.content.include?(/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i)
```

I want something like this. That example was for checking if the comment's content includes emails. But logically I get an "can't convert regexp to string" error.

How can you do the include? method in rails with an regexp? So, to check whether a text includes a string of a certain regex format?

Or is the controller the wrong place for such regex actions?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I do ruby regex'es this way:

```
stringObj.match(/regex/)
```

Answer (score 9):

There's also

```
if @comment.content =~ /regex/
```

If you had an array of all previous comments @prev_comments and wanted to replace them all in one shot, you could:

```
pattern = /#(\d+)/

@comment.content.gsub(pattern) do 
  cur_match = Regexp.last_match
  idx = cur_match[1].to_i - 1
  @prev_comments[idx]
end
```

Trick is using Regexp.last_match to get the current match, which made me wonder if it was thread safe.   It [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004245/is-regexp-last-match-thread-safe), apparently.

adapted (stolen) from the below more general String extension

```
class String
  def js_replace(pattern, &block)
    gsub(pattern) do |_|
      md = Regexp.last_match
      args = [md.to_s, md.captures, md.begin(0), self].flatten
      block.call(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

Source: http://vemod.net/string-js_replace

Answer (score 6):

To match the nature of .include?

```
 stringObj.match(/regex/).present?
```

Would give similar true/false outcomes if you're using Rails (or ActiveSupport)

Comment: Ruby match objects don't have `present?`.

Comment: Updated to note that you need to be using Rails or ActiveSupport to take advantage of present?